# state value is undefine in react js

Tags: reactjs

I get the data from the backend and store it into the state (post). when I use post.name then it shows undefined.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
   
    const getAllUser = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/getpost");
      response.json().then((res) => setPost(res.data.Post));
      // console.log(post);
    };
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
      getAllUser();
    }, []);
    
    const component = post.component;  // value is undefine
    console.log(component);
```

Comment: Hi! Probably you're trying to use post.name before it is loaded. You need to check if post is populated before trying to access post.name

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate if post is populated before accessing post.name.

If you're using babel, you can do it like this:

```
post?.name
```

If you're not using babel:

```
post ? post.name : 'empty'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pass I used the setState callback so now you might like to use:

https://maksimrv.medium.com/usestate-with-callback-d574298eb8bd

because you want to read a state variable's value immediately after it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try and handle all your async logic in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAllUser();
  
  async function getAllUser () {
    const response = fetch("http://localhost:4000/getpost");
     const json = await response.json()
     setPost(json.data.Post);
  // console.log(post);
};
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're manipulating the state, you should use `useEffect()`, for instance:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    // Do something with the updated post object here.
}, [ post ]);
```